# Virtualbox Networking: XP Guest, Ubuntu Host: Connecting to Windows servers & local network?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

**Here's what I have:**

- Windows XP running in VirtualBox 3.0.8_OSE r53138;
- Host OS = Ubuntu 9.10 "Karmic Koala";
- Windows network in my office with smb fileservers;
- Guest OS is connected to the internet and is sharing folders with Host OS;
- Limited networking expertise.

**Here's what I actually need to do:**

- Use MS Outlook in my XP guest with all its calendar-sharing features and stuff (if this is all done through the internet then great) - or find a Linux app that can do the same stuff;
- Map Windows network servers, eg. smb://server01/ in my XP guest (I can already access these in Ubuntu.

**Here's what I've tried with no luck:**

- Entering the server address (example above) in my XP guest windows explorer address bar (got a "could not access the file, path or drive" error message - maybe if I could enter login/pass information? But I don't know how);
- Mapping the server as a network drive (Windows could not find the path);
- Mounting the server as one of my shared folders (I couldn't find it through the shared folders browser in VirtualBox - is there somewhere in the Linux filesystem that Ubuntu keeps links to mounted servers?).

Comment: re the last bullet point: ~/.gvfs

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a HOWTO article for Linux Journal about this.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-windows-xp-virtualbox-linux

Following these directions allows the virtual machine to interact with your network as if it were an actual PC, including setting up network shares.  I'd suggest changing to Bridged Networking to interact more naturally with the rest of your network.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the Internet through the XP guest, then you should be fine. It's probably a matter of naming/resolution as to how you are trying to reference your server(s). Have you tried the IP address(es) directly (example: dir \192.168.1.2\net-share)?

Comment: Ah so I can access the smb:// server through its IP address eh? How do I find out what its IP address is?

Comment: Server administrator or "pinging" the "server name" on a working system.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to hazard a guess that the bit you are missing setting the configuration in VirtualBox for the network adapter of your virtual machine to say "**bridged**" networking as opposed to "**nat**". You might have some trouble accessing local area network things when set to nat networking because technically the guest os is in that case not part of the local network but is a node off of another node and the addresses are translated.

**If you set this to bridged, your guest os should become part of the same local network as the host**, allowing you to connect to browse samba shares by name and the like. It should be just like any other windows machine plugged into the network at that point.

Also, I Evolution is the linux mail program with the best outlook integration and calendaring, but when I say best I mean it's still a ways off the mark by all accounts. I pretty much avoid outlook/exchange like the plague tho so I'm just throwing this general answer out there.